# Relation between different definitions of types

Tags: type-theory, model-theory, lo.logic

Is there any connection between the [definition of type in model theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_%28model_theory%29) and the definitions from [type theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory)? Is there any explanation why the same term is used for these notions, maybe in the historical sense.

Comment: The question is too vague. On the surface, the two concepts are quite different. But the notion of type in model theory is very general, so types (in type theory) probably can be modelled by types (in model theory), but this is unlikely to be very interesting. What do you want to learn from answers to this question?

Comment: Please expand the question (using the "edit" link) with some explanation of your specific goals.

Comment: There is no historical connection between these two uses of the term *type*. That said, types in type theory naturally correspond to incomplete types (the sorts) for the associated multi-sorted first-order language.

Comment: -1 as per Scott's comment, though if this is edited soon I'm happy to reverse/rescind the downvote.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. It was posted a long time ago already, but I think that the answer from Francois is good enough. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no deep historical or mathematical connections between these two uses of the term *type*.

Comment: (Just to make my comment an answer.)